# Data being extracted to another worksheet is not correct

Tags: excel, vba

I have a "Data" worksheet that holds loads of data. It has 17 columns A-Q and in the G column is the date that is meant for dd/mm/yyyy. I have a separate worksheet called "NoEntry" and here is where I would like the dates to be entered by the user (Start-date L15 and End-date in L16) and once a button clicked all the data between and including the start and end date will go into another worksheet called "DateData".

The code I have below kind of works. The problem is that for some reason the data transferred over is not correct. Firstly, not all data keeps within the boundaries - some gets copied over with dates that are before the "start date". Another thing is that in the data there are blank records (A-F has data and onwards is blank) and some of them get copied over also - even though they have no date.

I feel like either its not looping correctly through all records or perhaps its a formatting issue. Perhaps is there a way to convert all the date column into a specific format before it does the copying - has to be dd/mm/yyyy. Or could just be something I'm missing?

**from testing it seems only one record got through that is before the start date but blank data still gets copied over the date used was 16/09/2019 to 07/10/2019**

Any help would be much appreciated,

Thanks :)

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim wsData As Worksheet, wsDate As Worksheet, wsNoEntry As Worksheet
Dim dSDate As Date, dEDate As Date
Dim lRowStart As Long, lRowEnd As Long
Dim aData() As Variant
Dim i As Long


'set the worksheet objects
Set wsData = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data")
Set wsDate = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DateData")
Set wsNoEntry = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("NoEntry")

'required variables
dSDate = wsNoEntry.Range("L15").Value
dEDate = wsNoEntry.Range("L16").Value

'set the array - you can make this dynamic!
aData = wsData.Range("A1:Z1000").Value

'for loop to find start
For i = 1 To 1000
    If aData(i, 7) = dSDate Then
        lRowStart = i
        Debug.Print "Start row = " & lRowStart
        Exit For
    End If
Next i

'now loop backwards to find end date
For i = 1000 To 1 Step -1
    If aData(i, 7) = dEDate Then
        lRowEnd = i
        Debug.Print "End row = " & lRowEnd
        Exit For
    End If
Next i

'now we have start and end dates
'going to use copy/ paste for simplicity
wsData.Range("A" & lRowStart, "Z" & lRowEnd).Copy
'paste in date sheet
wsDate.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
'clear clipboard
Application.CutCopyMode = False

Application.ScreenUpdating = True


End Sub
```

[Input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Xc5Q.png)

[Output - blacked out due to private information (G5 date shouldn't be there and you can see blanks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UU4OZ.png)

Comment: Could you provide screenshots of input and output?

Comment: @M.Schalk added now, as you can see one record got copied over G5 13/09/2019 and you can see some blanks

Comment: Your code is written to find the data inside a sorted dataset. It seems like your dataset is not sorted. You either need to sort your data or overhaul the logic of your selection algorithm.

Comment: @M.Schalk yes you're right, it is working now for some reason. I had a problem with is before that when I sorted the data, only the blank records would copy over but it seems to fine now